# Normalize the Kinect Skeleton Joints

Tags: image-processing, kinect

I'm working on a project to recognize people by their skeleton using Microsoft Kinect SDK.

The problem is that the skeleton size grows as the person moves towards the Kinect sensor. I need to build my system in a way to be independent of the position of the person. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Some related works say " the skeleton should be normalized in the time domain." , I don't know what that means!

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the normalization methods depends on the reason you need it. Maybe you can provide more information on why you would need a normalized skeleton.

Here are some methods that I can think of:

1. Compute a 3D bounding box (AABB) for the skeleton joints. Find the axis where the AABB is the largest and calculate a scale factor so that size would be 1.0. You can then apply this scaling factor on all other axes.
2. Maybe you want skeleton joints independent of their position. In this case, you can use a joint (e.g. spine) and consider that the origin of your skeleton. Then, compute every other joint position as:

   newjointPosition = oldjointPosition - spinePosition;

If you need a more specific answer, please tell us more about your app and requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me give an example to explain. When I measure the height of a person using the Kinect, I get different results depending on the position of the user (the distance between the user and the sensor). I want to get the same result no matter what the position of the user is.

Comment: How do you compute the height of the person at this moment?  I don't have a kinect right now to test, but as far as I remember the joint positions are in a 3D space. This means that it doesn't matter the distance from the sensor... the Y component should be constant.

Comment: This link says [link](http://studentguru.gr/b/vangos/archive/2012/05/07/kinect-for-windows-find-user-height-accurately.aspx) the height is the sum of the lengths of the following line segments:

Head - ShoulderCenter
ShoulderCenter - Spine
Spine - HipCenter
HipCenter - KneeLeft or KneeRight
KneeLeft / KneeRight - AnkleLeft / AnkleRight
AnkleLeft / AnkleRight - FootLeft / FootRight

Comment: The method seems fair, although it is susceptible to some degree of error (as the article also says). Do you see a big change in the measured user's height while he moves? What is the distance from the sensor you are standing at?

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong! and you are right. Now, I almost get the same height no matter the distance. But how? Could you please explain to me what do you mean by this " the joint positions are in a 3D space. This means that it doesn't matter the distance from the sensor... the Y component should be constant"?